# "Access to this path is denied" in Windows 7 application

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Ran into a strange phenomena:

- in Application A, the code:
  Using sr = New StreamReader(path)    
  runs perfectly (where path is C:\tmp for example. The directory is on the local machine).
- In Application B the same line, on the **same directory** throws the exception: "Access to the path is denied".

This happens when run in the IDE or by activating the exe file.

**Some additional information:**

Windows 7 Pro, 64bit VS 2013

- The app.manifest of both application is identical. I've tried changing to all possible options of requestedExecutionLevel but the result was the same.
- The target framework of the application is 4.
- The exception is thrown whether I run as administrator or not.
- I've set the permissions of the directory to full control for all accounts (including Administrator and Everyone).
- I've deleted the directory and recreated it. Didn't help.
- Ran Farbar scan which did not report any problems.

Comment: is the Application B running properly with any other drive than C? I have faced such a problem. You havent posted the code so..

Answer (score -1):

Application A is referencing the FILE C:\tmp.  I expect this file isnt present on Application B's machine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f2ke0fzy

Also ensure you are properly disposing of your StreamReader class after use.  if you dont do this the file can remain locked.

Comment: Application A and Application B are both on machine C so it is the same file

Comment: His code shows a `Using` statement so one assumes that the issue here is not the not disposal of the streamreader

Comment: As Matt deduced, both apps run on the same machine. C:\tmp is a directory, not a file.
In the meanwhile, I've checked what happens when I ensure that the directory is not read-only. Didn't help either.